# How to get dictionary items through javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I need to alert the dictionary items on page load.But so far no alert is getting displayed.Please help.

```
        data2 = {"iname": "name", "imodel": "dtls2"}
        return render(request, "home.html", data2)


       // inside home.html
       <script>

         for (var key in data2) {
          alert(data[key]);
         }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dump `data2` dict in Python part of your code to a JSON string.

```
import json

data2 = {"iname": "name", "imodel": "dtls2"}
data2_json = json.dumps(data2) 
return render(request, "home.html", {"data2": data2_json})
```

Then parse that JSON string using a `safe` filter in home.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let data = {{data2|safe}};
  for (var key in data) {
    alert(data[key]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite. The third parameter to `render` needs to be a dict: `return render(request, "home.html", {'data2': data2_json})`.

Comment: @MiaDavis Try now, I forgot to wrap data2 in {{}},; answer updated.

Comment: Try `let data = {{data2|safe}};`.

Comment: OK, now I have Django installed and actually tested the code. Hopefully, the final change is to use `alert(data[key]);` as in your question; answer updated.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for going in to so much trouble to help out. It is working now.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think by mistake you are writing `data[key]` change it to `data2[key]` because you are looping through `data2` not `data`

```
<script>

   for (var key in data2) {
     alert(data2[key]);
    }
 </script>
```